# message.guild.me is assigning the role to the bot, not the user issuing command

Tags: python, discord.py

Having an odd issue with my code. The bot is supposed to assign the new permission to the user who issued the command in Discord when message.guild.me is used, however it instead is assigning it to the bot. I verified also that this is the command that is adding the permission to the bot and also verified the user is not getting the permissions. According to Discord.py API guide, this is supposed to assign it to the user issuing the command (the "me" is what is supposed to do that). Any insight on what I could try instead or how to correct this?

Below is the code. There's a few bits of info missing but they shouldn't contribute to whats going on (for example, the time in the print command).

```
elif message.content.startswith('!disbute'):
        to_role = get(message.guild.roles, id=846420097156775956)
        autorize_role = get(guild.roles, name=role)
        overwrites = {
            message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
            message.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
            to_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)}
        channel = await message.guild.create_text_channel('dispute-regionals', overwrites=overwrites)
        print('Disbute regionals | Triggered: ' + time)
```

Answer (score 3):

`message.guild.me` refers to the bot client, use `message.author` to get the user who invoked the command.

And I highly recommend using `discord.ext.commands` for making commands instead of `on_message`

Comment: Beautiful, that worked. Not sure why I never thought to do that. Thanks! And I'll look into those commands as well. Thanks for the suggestion.